# Pushing the button down, just center after the text

Tags: html, css

How can I push the button down just after the text, as it stands now, it is stuck at the top before the text. It should go after the text:

Current result:[image]

Desired result:[image]

Here is the HTML/CSS markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CUSTOM ALERT BOX
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#alertBox_container {
    left: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    position: relative;
    color: rgb(11,63,113);
}
#alertBox {
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
#alertBox_titlebar {
    line-height:24px;
    width: 100%;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ffffff", endColorstr="#cdcdcd");
    font-weight: bold;
}
.alertBox_Button {
    color: #464646;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #999 #666 #666 #999;
    background-color:#ccc;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#ffffff', EndColorStr='#E7E7E7');
}
.alertBox_Button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;        
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#fafafa', EndColorStr='#dddddd');
    color: #000000;
}

#alertBox_close {
    line-height: 10px;
    width: 18px;

    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: bold;

    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}

#alertBox_text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

#alertBox_div_btn_OK {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#alertBox_btn_OK {
    height: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 9pt;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>


<!--            Start of custom alertbox                -->
<div id="alertBox">
    <div id="alertBox_container">
        <div id="alertBox_titlebar"><span style="padding-left: 3px;">IMTS</span></div>
        <div><input class="alertBox_Button" id="alertBox_close" type="button" value="X" onclick="alertBox_hide()"></div>
        <div id="alertBox_text">Searching the database...</div>
        <div id="alertBox_div_btn_OK"><input class="alertBox_Button" id="alertBox_btn_OK" type="button" value="OK" onclick="alertBox_hide()"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--            End of custom alertbox              -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you are positioning the elements absolutely within the box.  Get rid of that:

http://jsfiddle.net/qysTW/1

```
#alertBox_text {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#alertBox_div_btn_OK {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

You can then use `margin` to space them out properly.  Even the width and height shouldn't be needed unless there's something else on your greater page which this is overriding.